# How do I parse non-traditional dates in golang?

Tags: parsing, datetime, go

I have this date, in this format:

25.04.2016

I need to parse this into a Golang time object so that I can store it in my DB.

What is the best way to do so? I can't find a standard parsing format that will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse a date in go you provide a format string that represents the date `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006` so in this case it would look like;

```
t, _ := time.Parse("02.01.2006", "25.04.2016")
```

(play ground example; https://play.golang.org/p/6E9zshNeFG )

Check the packages docs here; https://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_Parse

I believe the arbitrary date you use as the example format is the first day of the Go programming language.